# Springboot Webclient throws "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Springboot Webclient throws "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error when trying to call rest api in  remote server.

When the server loads, the first server request loads fine. When I send the second request after some time (Say 5 mins), I am getting the error.

Webclient creation code:

```
WebClient webClient() {
           TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
               .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 30000)
               .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, false)
               .doOnConnected { connection ->
               connection.addHandlerLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE))
           connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(30))
                   .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(30))
               .addHandlerLast(new IdleStateHandler(30,30,30))

       }

       ReactorClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient))

       return WebClient.builder()
               .clientConnector(httpConnector)
               .build()

   }
```

Please find the logs below. It looks like the connection is not properly closed.

Could you please let me know how to resolve it?

```
2019-04-10 15:26:31.534  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-10 15:26:31.534  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-10 15:26:31.544  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2019-04-10 15:26:31.820 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [tcp] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-tcp, daemon=true, selectCount=4, workerCount=4}
2019-04-10 15:26:31.821 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [tcp] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: PooledConnectionProvider {name=tcp, poolFactory=reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$$Lambda$377/205810452@3af356f}
2019-04-10 15:26:32.127 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll       : Default Epoll support : false
2019-04-10 15:26:32.128 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue      : Default KQueue support : false
2019-04-10 15:26:32.131 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] i.n.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup    : -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
2019-04-10 15:26:32.161 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop        : -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
2019-04-10 15:26:32.161 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop        : -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
2019-04-10 15:26:32.165 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] i.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  : org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
2019-04-10 15:26:32.297  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : onSubscribe(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.SwitchIfEmptySubscriber)
2019-04-10 15:26:32.316  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : request(unbounded)
2019-04-10 15:26:32.362 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl             : netty-tcnative not in the classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable.
2019-04-10 15:26:32.903 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext       : Default protocols (JDK): [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1] 
2019-04-10 15:26:32.903 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext       : Default cipher suites (JDK): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
2019-04-10 15:26:32.929 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : Creating new client pool [tcp] for remoteserver.host.com:443
2019-04-10 15:26:32.945 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId        : -Dio.netty.processId: 235344 (auto-detected)
2019-04-10 15:26:33.242 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId        : -Dio.netty.machineId: 1c:4d:70:ff:fe:a5:c9:6d (auto-detected)
2019-04-10 15:26:33.287 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil              : -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
2019-04-10 15:26:33.287 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil              : -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
2019-04-10 15:26:33.287 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil              : -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
2019-04-10 15:26:33.309 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca] Created new pooled channel, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:26:33.343 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
2019-04-10 15:26:33.344 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
2019-04-10 15:26:33.346 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] i.n.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory     : Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@403ca90
2019-04-10 15:26:33.374 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider            : [id: 0xb38d8bca] SSL enabled using engine SSLEngineImpl and SNI remoteserver.host.com:443
2019-04-10 15:26:33.386 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0xb38d8bca] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (SimpleChannelPool$1#0 = io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool$1), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:33.617 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
2019-04-10 15:26:33.618 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2019-04-10 15:26:33.618 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2019-04-10 15:26:33.618 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2019-04-10 15:26:33.648 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Registering pool release on close event for channel
2019-04-10 15:26:33.648 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel connected, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:26:33.855 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler          : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2019-04-10 15:26:33.857 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}, [connected])
2019-04-10 15:26:33.887 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [configured])
2019-04-10 15:26:33.890 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://remoteserver.host.com/api/v1/Test, method=POST}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.014 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/v1/Test HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.8.6.RELEASE
host: remoteserver.host.com
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
2019-04-10 15:26:34.043 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object 
2019-04-10 15:26:34.050 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object EmptyLastHttpContent
2019-04-10 15:26:34.051 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [request_sent])
2019-04-10 15:26:34.229 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [LoggingHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.254 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [ReadTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.271 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [WriteTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.274 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [IdleStateHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, IdleStateHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.289 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, Server=Kestrel, Server-Timing=api;desc=dotREZ API;dur=7, cache;desc=Cache read/write;ct=1;dur=1, total;dur=8, X-Powered-By=ASP.NET, Set-Cookie=dtCookie=17$0D7C3AB4BE87B44D72811D72E8C4878F; Path=/; Domain=.test.com, Date=Wed, 10 Apr 2019 21:26:37 GMT, Set-Cookie=dotrez=67235850.20480.0000; path=/; Httponly; Secure]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.289 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [response_received])
2019-04-10 15:26:34.295  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : onNext(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse@5119d40e)
2019-04-10 15:26:34.337 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:false, inboundDone: false]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.338  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableSubscriber)
2019-04-10 15:26:34.338  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | request(unbounded)
2019-04-10 15:26:34.338  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : onComplete()
2019-04-10 15:26:34.346 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Received last HTTP packet
2019-04-10 15:26:34.347  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | onNext({"data":{"result"}})
2019-04-10 15:26:34.354  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | onComplete()
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: LoggingHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: IdleStateHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [disconnecting])
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Releasing channel
2019-04-10 15:26:34.356 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:34:27.178  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : onSubscribe(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.SwitchIfEmptySubscriber)
2019-04-10 15:34:27.179  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : request(unbounded)
2019-04-10 15:34:27.184 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:34:27.184 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://remoteserver.host.com/api/v1/Test, method=POST}
2019-04-10 15:34:27.185 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/v1/Test HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.8.6.RELEASE
host: remoteserver.host.com
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
2019-04-10 15:34:27.187 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object 
2019-04-10 15:34:27.187 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object EmptyLastHttpContent
2019-04-10 15:34:27.188 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [request_sent])
2019-04-10 15:34:27.188 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [LoggingHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:27.189 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [ReadTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:27.189 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [WriteTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:27.189 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [IdleStateHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, IdleStateHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:46.395  WARN 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] The connection observed an error

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1125) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347) ~[netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148) ~[netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) [netty-common-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]

2019-04-10 15:34:46.396 ERROR 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : onError(java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
2019-04-10 15:34:46.397 ERROR 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : 

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

2019-04-10 15:34:46.398 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel closed, now 0 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: LoggingHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(LoggingHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(ReadTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(WriteTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: IdleStateHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(IdleStateHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.414 ERROR 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
```

Comment: Please enable `wiretap(true)` to inspect the traffic between the server and the client.

Comment: The same log is shown when set wiretap(true). `Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections`. Channel uses the connection which is already closed by remote host. Is there anything else we can try?

Comment: I had a similar issue with WebClient - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233216/spring-webflux-webclient-logs-connection-reset-by-peer. I upgraded to latest version of reactor netty but couldn't get rid of the issue. Finally, I gave up and used RestTemplate wrapping the response in a Mono.

Comment: If you have a reproducible scenario please report an issue for Reactor Netty

Comment: @chom I am not getting response instead getting 500 server error. Did you see any performance affect using resttemplate?

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva I have tried with 2 different hosts. I am getting this error for one host only which is developed in .net. Do you know any issues when connecting rest with .net app?

Comment: @Viswa I didn't notice any performance effect. You can try switching to RestTemplate and see if you are still getting the error. If you are, then it is the issue with the endpoint you are consuming. I think it helps at least to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @chom Did you use the AsyncRestTemplate?.. can you provide your code just I don't  miss any config..

Comment: @Viswa I didn't use AsyncRestTemplate. I used like this

`Mono<ResponseEntity<x>> response = Mono.just(restTemplate.getForEntity(url, x.class));`

Comment: @chom I did try the RestTemplate and AsyncRestTemplate, when I run the load test, I get the Address already in use bind excpetions.

Comment: Opened an issue for this at Reactor Netty: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/764